# Capture HTTP response & Header in Loadrunner

Tags: rest, http, httpresponse, loadrunner

We are using REST in our APIs. We are trying to capture the HTTP response and HTTP response Header data in HP Loadrunner to perform load test. Could someone kindly tell how it can be acheived ?

Regards
Amit

Comment: Your question is directly related to the topic of 'Correlation' which is covered in the training material, the tutorial, examples in help online as well as the documentation.  if your management has not seen fit to provide you an opportunity for training then you should seek to improve your management options with other organizations

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this blog post](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-LoadRunner-and-Performance/Load-testing-of-a-REST-API-using-HP-LoadRunner-s-web-custom/ba-p/6174105#.VcBPs_kyh-4)